# unable to launch configure visual studio development web server error in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

I was using `Visual Studio 2012` it was working nice, but when I install `Visual Studio 2013` and then try to run a project in **`Visual Studio 2012`**, it gives me this error

**`unable to launch configure visual studio development web server`**

[image]

please help me to solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.  I edited the hosts file  which had an entry for local host like ::localhost.  I commented this line out and it started working.